# check owners of run control scripts

Tags: linux, find, owner

To secure my computer I want to be sure that only "root", "sys", "bin" are owners of run control scripts..

This is what I get so far :

```
find -L /etc/rc* -ls | awk '$5 !="root" { print $0 }'
```

is there a better way to achieve this ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all files not owned by root use:

```
find -L /etc/rc* ! -user root
```

To check for all three user names named in the question use:

```
find -L /etc/rc* ! -user sys -a ! -user sys -a ! -user bin
```